# Best book for self study: quotient subspace

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying linear algebra all over again, but when I reach quotient subspace I don't know what is happening. I'm stuck in that topic. Any recommendation for a nice explanation in a book or online material to get intuition and make more mathematical problems?

Note: I'm currently studying from Linear algebra by Friedberg and linear algebra by Hoffman.

Comment: Just study equivalence relation and cosets properly. You will find many videos on youtube and many notes on internet. Gallian is pretty basic but it explains cosets for groups, which every vector space is also one. I hope you know about groups.

Comment: The prototype for this is modular arithmetic. Since I don't know you I am not certain that the connection between the two would be evident or make anything clearer.

Comment: As John Douma has alluded to, there is a certain degree of difficulty when one's first exposure to quotient structures is in vector spaces. People who study abstract algebra before linear algebra see quotients of groups and rings before quotients of vector spaces. If you have some time to invest in this (i.e., if you are going to study this eventually and have a bit of time now), you could learn some of the fundamentals of group theory, for example in *Algebra* by Godement or *Algebra* by Artin. Studying group homomorphisms will also help with linear mappings.

Comment: If you don't have time for that, then you probably just need to get help with the specific things you find difficult in F-I-S and H-K, the way they're explained there. It's not clear that other books which only look at vector spaces will have better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You could read about It on classical Books as Topica in Algebra of N. Herstein or Algebra of M. Artin for example.